# Is it possible to have $2$ absolute maximums?

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

I am asked to fine the absolute extrema of this function on the interval $[-1,1]$:

[image: Function]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcLLt.jpg)

I know the absolute minimum is $0,0$. But are points $(-1,2)$ and $(1,2)$ both absolute maximums or are they local maximums?

Comment: They are both absolute maxima. But it looks to me like the function has negative values when the input is above $2$ or below $-2$, which would mean that $(0,0)$ is not an absolute minimum, but rather just a local minimum.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Sorry, it should say that there is a restriction of [-1,1]

Comment: Obviously not, by definition. But it looks like what you're asking about is *whether it is possible for a function to become greatest at more than one point,* which is obviously yes. The $\sin(\cdot)$ even attains its extreme values infinitely many times.

Comment: @realism98 If my answer is satisfactory, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute/global maximum refers to the largest value attained by $f$ over the domain. The points at which this value is attained are called points of global maximum. In short, there is only one global maximum (if it exists) but there may be many points of global maximum.

In your case, the global maximum is $2$ and global maximum points are $1,-1$.